# How to calculate previous month from current month in SSRS with format MM-YYYY

Tags: reporting-services

i want to calculate previous months from current month in SSRS with the format like this: MM-YYYY, for example: 10-2016,11-2016

Can you please help me how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this for month previuos to current month:

```
=Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, Today), "MM-yyyy")
```

First you `DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, ...)` substract one month from the date you specified (`...`), and then format the result date. To get required month you need to set -1, -2, ..., -n appropriately.